# Checking the pair rows using SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-partitioning, database-cursor

Sample Database:

```
workerid    codes   empl_rcd
123 USA 0
123 NY  0
123 SF  0
123 USA 1
123 NY  1
567 USA 1
567 CA  1
567 CA  2
567 NY  1
890 USA 0
890 NY  0
890 USA 2
890 NY  1
```

requirement: for each worker if USA is present check the corresponding NY is present or not

e.g for worker 123 if USA 0 is present then check NY 0 is present or not
if USA 1 is present then check NY 1 is present or not 
similar for other workerids also

Resultant output should be :

```
123 USA 0
123 NY  0
123 USA 1
123 NY  1
567 USA 1
567 NY  1
890 USA 0
890 NY  0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As posted this makes no sense to me at all. It is like there is just random output. Can you try to clarify the requirements?

Comment: is the flag used in your Pseudo code?  how come I don't see fam_flag 3 in the output example?

Comment: @blueprogrammer Was trying to give an example of row pairs in DB, failed. edited with new example. Sorry

Comment: (1) Why do you need the `CODES` column? You know it is always going to be `USA` and `NY`. (2) Is `workerid, codes, empl_rcd` guaranteed to be unique? If not what if there are duplicates for `123 USA 0` and `123 NY  0` for example?

Comment: 1) Yes it will be USA-NY pair. 2)Not guaranteed to be unique, if duplicate is present it will be in  pairs if 123 USA 0 , then 123 NY 0 should be there

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from yourtable f1
where f1.codes in ('USA', 'NY') 
and exists
(
   select * from yourtable f2
   where (f1.codes='USA' and f2.codes='NY'   or f1.codes='NY' and f2.codes='USA')
   and f1.workerid=f2.workerid and f1.empl_rcd=f2.empl_rcd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2:

```
with perimeter as (
select f1.*, case when f1.codes='USA' then 'NY' else 'USA' end CodesSearch
from yourtable f1
where f1.codes in ('USA', 'NY') 
)
select f1.* from perimeter f1
and exists
(
   select * from perimeter f2
   where f1.CodesSearch=f2.codes and f1.workerid=f2.workerid and f1.empl_rcd=f2.empl_rcd
)
```

Comment: care to explain a little bit?

Comment: With take perimeter, and then i do a query on perimeter where the same exists